# Does image appear larger on phone with higher PPI.

Tags: android, ios, png, ppi

I have a png which is `96 X 96`. I have two Android phones which have the same screen size but one phone has a higher PPI.

Will this image appear larger on phone with higher PPI?

If so why?

I looked through some documentation but could not find any answer there.

Comment: depends on how you're telling android to draw the image. if you say "make this image appear 1cm x 1cm" on screen, it'll be 1cm no matter what the PPI is. If you say "draw it 96px", then you'll get a smaller image on the higher ppi screen.

Comment: how do you tell android to draw the image ? is there a tutorial on it ?

Comment: 96x96px image appears larger on a LOWER ppi devices because the physical size of pixels on that kind of devices is bigger than those of higher ppi.

Comment: @Onik: right. I would also have guessed an image would get *smaller*, if it was drawn using the "native" pixel density. Seems the OP has some strange hardware, then.